# MySQL Single update query, without updating non-null values

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Given an SQL statement:

`const string UpdateString = @"UPDATE users SET hash=@new_hash, firstname=@new_firstname, lastname=@new_lastname WHERE id=@id";`

I then load in to an MySqlCommand object:

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdateString , connection))
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_hash", hash);
```

If I don't add all the parameters I get an exception thrown.

How can I update only say, the firstname, but not the hash without having to write an individual update command string for each possible combination of individual or grouped column updates?

Comment: Why the downvote? Easy to click the down arrow but not type and leave a constructive comment?! Juergen's answer was spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to update the `hash` then add `null` for that parameter with this query

```
UPDATE users 
SET hash = case when @new_hash is null then hash else @new_hash end, 
    firstname = @new_firstname, 
    lastname = @new_lastname 
WHERE id = @id
```